# Git\Gerrit remote rejected with "missing Change-Id in commit message footer"

Tags: git, gerrit

First, let me confess that I am not a git-guru, not even a git-newbie. We have gerrit installed and I am able to commit changes to the repo... some times. Here is the steps that I follow:

1. `git add file.txt`

   `git add file2.txt` ..... and so on
2. `git commit -m"My awesome commit message"`
3. `git push origin master:refs/for/master`

This works 9 out of 10 times but 1 out of 10 times I get "missing Change-Id in commit message footer" I then do git commit --amend and I can see that the commit message is there.

This is where I rant because I do not understand why I am getting the issue... sometimes. The current commit --amend shows my message at the top, a blank line and then the line with the Change-Id: in it. Then another blank line and the just lines with comments below that (added by .... git?)

How do I fix this and how do I fix it permanently so that I never get it again? I admit that it is a lack of knowledge on my part - 100%

This is what I get after: git commit --amend:
[image]

Comment: Ok, this is just annoying ... There is a blank line below my commit message and another below the Change-Id:

Comment: No... this is totally right... this is the way it works.

Comment: SInce git-clone does not download the hook commit-msg which generates Change-Id, you could copy this commit-msg to `/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks` for Ubuntu, and `/mingw64/share/git-core/templates/hooks` or `/mingw32/share/git-core/templates/hooks` for Windows. So whenever you clone or init a git repo, this hook can be deployed into the current repo automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Gerrit demands that the Change-Id line MUST be located at the last paragraph of the commit message.

You need to understand why there're some lines after the Change-Id. Is there any hook being executed when you commit?

UPDATE:

There's nothing wrong with your commit message:

1. The Change-Id line was added automatically by commit-msg hook and it is correct.
2. The blank line is OK too... it was added automatically to separate your message from the Change-Id
3. The commented lines are a Git thing... just pay attention: "Lines starting with '#' will be ignored". Just ignore them.

After you save your commit execute:

```
git log
```

To verify your commit.

So, what is the issue? Why Gerrit is reporting "missing Change-Id"?

Because probably the issue is not in the last commit! Probably the issue (the lack of Change-Id) is on a parent commit. Execute the "git log" command and inspect your commit history looking for any new commit without the Change-Id.

Comment: I do think the hook is executed because if i go back and enter git commit --amend then I do see the Change-Id:

Comment: Yes. If you're not adding the Change-Id manually then you have the .git/hooks/commit-msg hook installed in your repository (you can check this) which is adding the Change-Id automatically. When I said "you need to understand why there're some lines after the Change-Id" I meant: why some times the Change-Id is generated correctly and some times some "strange" lines are added at the end? Please, add to your question a commit message example with the extra lines after the Change-Id.

Comment: Added to the original question. I even tried to remove everything after the Change-Id and that did not work. The steps that I followed: 1: git add 2: git commit 3: git push origin master:refs/for/master
  
Then I get the message.... I do git commit --amend and remove all lines after the Change-Id with no luck. Even when I remove the change-Id it does not help but a new Change-Id is created.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I will do this next time I run into this and update the ticket

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a requirement of Gerrit

> With this error message Gerrit rejects to push a commit to a project
>   which is configured to always require a Change-Id in the commit
>   message if the commit message of the pushed commit does not contain a
>   Change-Id in the footer (the last paragraph).
>
> This error may happen for different reasons:
>
> ```
> 1. missing Change-Id in the commit message
>
> 2. Change-Id is contained in the commit message but not in the last paragraph
> ```

[Missing Change-Id in commit message footer issue](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-missing-changeid.html)

Comment: This is not a Gerrit issue... this is exactly how Gerrit works.

Comment: All I meant is that it had nothing to do with git itself.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I did't understand you.

Comment: I have changed the answer to avoid confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check and add the commit-msg file in the .git/hooks folder of project. then do a git reset HEAD~ and then push code changes after adding file